# Ip address not changing in a for loop

Tags: python

*I'm using wmi to change my ip address but it doesnt work in a for loop*

```
import webbrowser
import random
import ipaddress
import socket
import wmi
import time as t

ip = u'174.116.16.133'
subnetmask = u'255.255.255.0'
gateway = u'192.168.0.1'

AustraliaIP = u'154.6.147.45'
BelgiumIP = u'181.214.218.233'
BrazilIP = u'188.241.177.133'
CanadaIP = u'174.116.16.133'
FranceIP = u'51.75.5.209'
GermanyIP = u'45.136.153.58'
HongKongIP = u'47.242.48.178'
IrelandIP = u'84.247.48.56'
ItalyIP = u'84.17.58.117'
JapanIP = u'156.146.35.22'
MexicoIP = u'77.81.142.138'
UnitedStatesIP = u'192.241.129.46'


IPList = [AustraliaIP, BelgiumIP, BrazilIP, CanadaIP, FranceIP, GermanyIP, HongKongIP, IrelandIP, ItalyIP, JapanIP, MexicoIP, UnitedStatesIP]

for i in IPList:
    t.sleep(20)
    print(i)
    nic.EnableStatic(IPAddress=[i], SubnetMask=[subnetmask]) #here is where i change the ip address
    nic.SetGateways(DefaultIPGateway=[gateway]) #here too
```

The bottom for loop is where i change the ip addresses. Whenever i check websites like https://whatismyipaddress.com/ it shows that the ip hasnt changed

Comment: .What is `nic`?

Comment: does the print shows the right ip?

Comment: Could you add your output from the for loop?

Comment: IP address and its gateway should be on the same network, right? or am I missing something?

Comment: Try doing a google search or check the documentation of what you are using.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how this works. I can say I live at the White House all I want, that doesn't mean the mailman is going to send mail addressed to White House to me.

https://whatismyipaddress.com/ shows the IP that your ISP has assigned to your router. The actual IP your computer has will be a private IP (like 192.168.0.1) that has been assigned to your computer by your router.
Your router then performs "network address translation" (NAT), so that you can actually communicate with the outside world.

Unless you're using a switch (rather than a router), your attempts to set your IP will be ignored. Routers use "dynamic host configuration protocol" (DHCP) to assign IPs to the devices connecting to them. They know which IPs they have assigned and to whom, and only forward traffic down the ports they think have  given an IP to. Switches are different and just blindly rebroadcast all the traffic they get to every device they are connected to.

Static IPs with routers are usually obtained using "DHCP reservation". You tell your router to always give the device that has a specific MAC address a given IP.

Finally, your ISP assigns you an IP (using DCHP). So even if you directly connect your computer to the internet, you cannot just declare your IP is whatever you want. Your ISP is not going to forward traffic to you that it thinks should be going to another country. 154.6.147.45 is an Australian IP because it is assigned to a machine in Australia, it is not some intrinsic property of the IP address.